# find the largest four digit prime number ending with $53$

Tags: number-theory

I have started something like below but not able to make any progress :

Say the number is $ab53$
$1000a+100b + 53 = p$

$1000a+100b = p-53$

that means $100 | p-53$

Comment: I'd try $9953$ and then count down by $100$s.

Comment: brute force check till you find a prime ?

Comment: There's not much more you can do, I'd guess.

Comment: http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt  largest is 8753, im hoping if there is some clever way to avoid checking few numbers in between. I feel this exercise is pointless if all i need to do is to check each number :/ I wont be learning anything from this

Comment: Would certainly be nice, but finding primes is usually hard.

Comment: We can tell from Dirichlet that the number of primes from $1$ to $N$ of the form $100k+53$ will be approximately $1/40$th of all primes from $1$ to $N$, for large $N$, but their specific local distribution is still mysterious.

Comment: Well, multiples of 3 are easy to avoid.  It can be a lot easier to show a number is composite than to show a number is prime.

Comment: This kind of question is pointless, so the objective is to spend as little time on it as possible. The fastest way is to write a one-line math software program, eg For[n = 9953, n > 0, n = n - 100, If[PrimeQ[n], Print[n], 1]] in Mathematica which prints a list of all primes ending in 53 less than 9954.

Comment: All primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6n\pm1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I'd skip a $100$ every $3$ of them (so $9953,9853,9653,9553,9353,9253$...

Comment: Sure, plenty of tricks to avoid some 'obvious non-primes, but those have minor significance on computational complexity, since we quickly find the ones you've elided are divisible by $3$. @barakmanos

Comment: Your best bet is probably writing out the list of 90 numbers from 1053 to 9953 and then manually implementing something like a sieve for all the primes from 2 to 97, basically the basis of the quadratic sieve or sieve of Eristothenediflj whatever his name was.

Comment: @DanielV The name is [Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes) (Ἐρατοσθένης).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this by hand you probably want to implement a sieve.  I would recommend:

- Write out all values to be sieved: $S = \{1053, 1153, 1253, ...\}$
- Then repeatedly:

  - Manually factor the largest number in the sieve $N = p_1^{a_1}\,p_2^{a_2}\,p_3^{a_3}\,\dots$
  - All of the values $N - 100p_k$ will be divisible by $p_k$
  - So cross out all values in the sieve from the sequence $N - 100p_k$ because they won't be prime

So, for example, starting with $N = 9953$, factor it to get $9953 = 37 \cdot 269$.  Then you know that 
  $$\{2553, 6253, 9953\} \text{ are all divisible by 37 no other sieve values are }$$

Then check $N = 9853$, factor it to get $9853 = 59 \cdot 167$, so you can cross out
  $$\{9853, 4153\} \text{ are all divisible by 59 no other sieve values are }$$

For each successive sieve you don't need to check the primes that have already been crossed out.

---

The reason this works is because you are solving the intersection of 2 arithmetic sequences:

$$\begin{cases}z = 100k_1 + 53 \quad \text{ for } k_1 \ge 10\\
z = Pk_2 + 0\end{cases}$$

...for primes $P$ from $2$ to $97$ (because $101^2 > 10000$), which is basically a very small chinese remainder representation problem.  $P=2$ and $P=5$ will have no intersection because $\gcd(100,5) \ne 1$ and $\gcd(100,2) \ne 1$.

Working it out:

$$\begin{cases} z \equiv 53 \pmod {100} \\
z \equiv 0 \pmod P\end{cases}$$

$$Pk_2 \equiv 53 \pmod {100}$$
$$k_2 = P^{-1}53 \pmod {100}$$

$$z = P(\underbrace{P^{-1}}_{\pmod {100}}53 + 100k_1)$$
$$z = P\underbrace{P^{-1}}_{\pmod {100}}53 + 100Pk_1$$

You could also invert the top approach and (as long as you are comfortable computing modular inverses) directly determine which sieve values are divisible by $P$ without resorting to a lengthy factoring process.

For example, if you wanted to sieve out all of the $100k_1 + 53$ that are divisible by $11$:
$$z = 11(11^{-1})53 + 100(11)k_1$$
$$z = 11\cdot 91 \cdot 53 + 1100k_1$$
$$z = 53053 + 1100k_1$$
$$z = 253 + 1100k_1$$

So you can cross out $$\{1353, 2453, 3553, ...\}$$

Answer (score 2):

I am learning a bit of Haskell, and got a kick out of writing this code:

First define the primes (I did not write this part)

```
primes = sieve [2..]
  where
    sieve (p:qs) = p : sieve [ q | q<-qs, q `mod` p /= 0 ]
```

Then the following one-liner returns 8753:

```
last $ takeWhile (<9999) [ p | p<-primes, p `mod` 100 == 53 ]
```

Comment: That answer might be considered off topic, but not everyone can afford mathematica or maple. You can get haskell system for free, though. And it seems a great language for exploring some simple mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

10^33-47
10^48-47
10^74-47
10^231-47
10^3206-47
10^4544-47
10^7064-47

all digits are 9 execpt last two are "53"

True these are larger than 4 digits, the largest 4 digits number ending in 53 is 8753

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial.

You can observe that $111=37\times 3$ so that $37|9953 = 9990-37$. Working with low primes - $3, 7, 11$ - eliminates some possibilities.

But to eliminate $9853 = 59\times 167$ or $9553=41\times 233$ requires more than a trick. Even $9353=47\times 199$ could be hard to spot, and you also need to eliminate $9253=19\times 487$.

It looks to me like a systematic approach is essential.